# Simply SSO in one domain

Tags: php, single-sign-on

I created simply scriptsso to login to my two applications in the same domain.

In app A I'm generating token with user name then I'm saving this date in storage.

```
$token = $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'].'&'.$user;   
file_put_contents('/'.$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'].'.txt',$token);
```

App B check if exists file with session_id = $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']

```
if(file_exists('../../appA/'.$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'].'.txt'))
{
    $token = file_get_contents('../../appA/'.$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'].'.txt');
    fclose();
  
    //Decode Token
    $token_code = preg_replace('/&.*/s','', $token);
    $token_user = preg_replace('/.*&/s','', $token);
    $whitelist = explode(',', "127.0.0.1","127.0.0.2");

    $result = app_dbQuery("SELECT user FROM 'users` WHERE `user` = $token_email LIMIT 1");
    if((app_dbNumRows($result) == true) && ($token_code == $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']) && (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$whitelist)))
    {
        header('Set-Cookie: CookieToken='.$_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"].'; Domain=abc.com; Path=/; Secure;');
        
        echo "login";
    }
}
```

If all ok, script is generating CookieToken which is next checked in header.php App B.

```
if((!file_exists('../../appA/'.$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'].'.txt')) && ($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] != $_COOKIE['CookieToken']))
{
  session_unset(); 
  if(isset($_COOKIE['CookieToken']))
  {
    header('Location: ../../appA/logout.php');
  }
  
}
```

When click logout.php, file token is remove and when someone doesn't click logout.php or browser get close then system remove all file token in storage older than 24 hours. What do you think about my idea about simply SSO, login two apps with the same domain?

Comment: I'm not convince that is usefull. If the 2 app are sharing the same session, you can just put the user info in $_SESSION from app A and get it back in app B.

Comment: @svgta Your idea is good, but do you have any ideas for securing the session because if I added username to PHPSESSID, this value will be see in cokies? Now I have a session regeneration so I don't think someone will inject the session id


**`if(!isset($_SESSION['initiate']))
{
 session_regenerate_id();
 $new_session_id = session_id();
 session_write_close();
 session_id($new_session_id);
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['initiate'] = 1;
}`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to change the session ID.
In a simple way, you can do something like this for app A:

```
<?php
session_start();
//do what you need
//...
if(!isset($_SESSION['sso'])
   $_SESSION['sso'] = [];
$_SESSION['sso']['user'] = $user;
$_SESSION['sso']['other_info'] = $other_info;
//...
```

The cookie on the webbrowser will only have the session ID as value. No other information is set in it. The $_SESSION datas are in the session manager of your server.

In app B, you have just to take the value of $_SESSION :

```
<?php
session_start();
//...
if(isset($_SESSION['sso'])){
   $user = isset($_SESSION['sso']['user']) ? $_SESSION['sso']['user'] : null;
   //do the control with your database
}
//...
```

But, for use session like that, becareful about the session manager of your 2 app :

- if it's PHP or file : the 2 app have to be on the same server and share the same session manager
- if you use 2 servers, one for each app, or use clusters : the session manager must be external like memcache or redis or database.

Comment: Thank you for help, your solution is works, but is solution  is save? I have 2 apps in the same domain.

Comment: The solution is not less secure of what you wanted to do with your token file. Don't forget to activate secure and httponly flags for the session. If you want something very secure, the work to do is not the same. You may need to use a real SSO provider like for openId Connect, oauth2 or SAML V2. But it's not as simple as that.

Comment: I closed script sso with my adress IP so i think this solution will be work go.